# Running JavaScript in WebView with LoadData after getting data from post request

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I want to run javascript in android in webview with loadData method of webview, after getting html in string form through a post request. Here is my code. I have searched many links but no one was according to my scenario. Any help?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    WebView wv;
    String result;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         

         wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
         Thread t= new Thread(new Runnable() {  
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                postData();
            }

        });
        t.start();
        while(t.isAlive());
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadData(result, "text/html", null);


    }
    public void postData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://result.abc.com/Home1/R2");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value1", "5001"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value2", "201214"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value3", "212"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value4", "ABC"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {           
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {                       
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you place this two line of code after getting result of the post request.

```
 wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 wv.loadData(result, "text/html", null);
```

after `result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`
so, final code look like this ::

```
result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadData(result, "text/html", null);
```

Comment: These 2 lines are already written after thread finishes its task. If you write the loading task of webview in another thread (i.e webView.load(...)) then you will get a runtime exception. "All webview methods must be called on same thread"

Comment: also try this wv.loadData(result, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);

Comment: Why  you understand that javascript is not running.

Comment: When I get Html through post request. It contains some function and it is called in body tag with onload. This is not running. I have to run it.

Comment: instead of run(), why don't you try asynctask? because you are facing 'all webveiw methods should be called on same thread'?